# Yii2 change url structure

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

Instead of have:

```
http://www.example.com/affiliate?ref=123456546546
```

I prefer to have

```
http://www.example.com/affiliate/ref/123456546546
```

Is it possible to pass GET param without changing `.htaccess` and keep my desired structure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add an rule to your UrlManager I guess your controller is affiliate and your action `index`

```
'urlManager' => [
...
   'rules' => [
      '<controller:(affiliate)>/ref/<ref:\d+>' => '<controller>/index',
   ]
...
]
```

I guess if you set custom rules you also have to add the following so that the default url's are still working.

```
 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```